# Real solution of exponential equation

Tags: calculus

[1] Total no. of real solution of the equation $2^x = 1+x^2$

[2] Total no. of real solution of the equation $4^x = x^2$

[3] Total no. of real solution of the equation $2^x+3^x+4^x = x^2$

[4] Total no. of real solution of the equation $3^x+4^x+5^x = 1+x^2$

My Try:: [1] Here $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ are solution of Given equation.

Now we will check for other solution which are exists or not

Let $f(x) = 2^x-x^2-1$ , Then $f^{'}(x) = 2^x \ln (2)-2x$ and $f^{''}(x) = 2^x\left(\ln(2)\right)^2-2$

Now we will check the Interval of $x$ in which function $f(x)$ is Increasing or decreasing.

$f^{'}(x)=2^x \cdot \ln (2)-2x >0$ for $x\leq 0$

Now I did not understand How can i proceed after that

plz help me

Thanks

Comment: The first derivative tells you the slope at various points, the second tells you the slope of the slope (so to speak).  We use the second derivative to find inflection points (where the function changes direction); these are at $f''(x) = 0$.  We use the first derivative to see the slope at the inflection points, to find out where troughs and peaks are.  Then we can determine bounded intervals where $f(x)$ crosses $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** First note that there are no negative solutions. For $2^x$ is increasing in the interval $(-\infty,0)$, while the function $1+x^2$ is decreasing. And there is a root at $x=0$.

Now I would prefer to take the ln of both sides, and consider the equation 
$x\ln 2=\ln(1+x^2)$. So let 
$$f(x)=x\ln 2-\ln(1+x^2).$$
We have 
$$f'(x)=\ln 2-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.$$
This is positive whenever $x^2\ln 2-2x+\ln 2$ is positive.

The roots of the quadratic are roughly $0.4$ and $2.5$. So the function is increasing up to about $0.4$, then decreasing in roughly the interval $(0.4,2.5)$.

The function reaches $0$ at $x=1$. Then it decreases for a while, and then starts to increase. In the long run, $2^x$ is much larger than $1+x^2$, so there is an additional root somewhere beyond $x=2.5$.

**Problem 2:** For the equation $4^x=x^2$, note that $4^x$ is increasing, and $x^2$ is decreasing in the interval $(-\infty,0)$. Since $4^x$ is below $x^2$ for large negative $x$, and above at $x=0$, there is exactly one negative root.

To look for positive roots, it is easier to look at the equivalent $2^x=x$, or equivalently, taking logarithms, at $x\ln 2-x$.

Let $f(x)=x\ln 2-\ln x$. Then $f'(x)=\ln 2-\frac{1}{x}$. Thus $f$ decreases in the interval $(0,\ln 2)$, then increases. The minimum alue of $f(x)$ is positive, so there are no positive roots.